# Securing HSM-stored symmetric data encryption keys (AES) in memory on server

Tags: encryption, key-management, hsm

My project requires me to encrypt sensitive user data using symmetric data encryption (AES). I will be storing the AES key (DEK) in a HSM-based key management service (ie. Azure Key Vault / AWS KMS) and will retrieve the key to encrypt/decrypt data on my Nodejs server.

I have scoured the internets for best practices, however, details and explanations only seem to go so far as to whether keys should be stored in the database,hard-coded or externally (ie. HSM, KMS, env var, etc ...).

I have not been able to find sufficient clarification on the following:

1) Should I create a different AES data encryption key for each user? If so, what is the reasoning behind this? Just another layer of complexity?

2) How best to secure the key against attacked like when the server is hacked and traced / monitored?

3) Is it better practice to retrieve the key at startup of the server, then store the key in memory on the server, OR retrieve the key each time the server needs to encrypt data for the user?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I newer worked with Azure Key Vault / AWS KMS, but if you are actually able to get the private key and store it in memory, why would you even use this services? If it works as intended, you should be able to decrypt and encrypt stuff but never get the key!

Comment: That's not how an HSM works. The key never leaves the HSM. It does the encryption/decryption for you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've asked several questions here, so I'm going to provide several answers, and a couple of clarifications.

> I will be storing the AES key (DEK) in a HSM-based key management service (ie. Azure Key Vault / AWS KMS) and will retrieve the key to encrypt/decrypt data on my Nodejs server.

This is not generally what you want to do.  If you're using an HSM, the goal is for the key to stay *inside* the HSM, and never leave.  One common way to accomplish this is to store a key-encryption-key (KEK) in the HSM, and encrypted data-encryption-key(s) (DEK) elsewhere.  In the case of Azure Key Vault, these could be retrievable secrets.  I'm sure Amazon has something similar.  Then, when you need to use a DEK, you pass it in to the HSM, where it is decrypted using the KEK, and then returned to you.

> 1) Should I create a different AES data encryption key for each user? If so, what is the reasoning behind this? Just another layer of complexity?

Yes.  The reason is that if a key is compromised, all of the data is not, only the data encrypted with this key.  (The data for one customer, in other words.) In addition, it eliminates the ability of many application flaws (outside of flaws specifically related to key retrieval) to allow one customer to accidentally gain access to another customer's data.

> 2) How best to secure the key against attacked like when the server is hacked and traced / monitored?

Secure your servers.  And follow the rest of the advice here, like only exposing keys when needed.

> 3) Is it better practice to retrieve the key at startup of the server, then store the key in memory on the server, OR retrieve the key each time the server needs to encrypt data for the user?

It is best to expose the keys for the minimum amount of time required to perform the encryption or decryption operations they need to perform.  Retrieving them every time the server starts certainly sounds excessive.  Whether it makes the most sense for you to retrieve them say, when a user logs in, or wait until an actual crypto operation needs to be performed is up to your judgement.  Again, the smaller the window the better, within reason.

Answer (score 0):

when the key is on an HSM technically you shouldnt be able to get it out that quickly in the first place.

if possible, require the HSM to require a special authentication to explicitly throw the keys.

an HSM is not only for safe storage of the keys, but usually they also can perform crypto operations like signing, de/encryption etc.

so depending whether or not your HSM lets you do it, set up a "basic user level" which can only operate with the key and an "administrative level", which actually has access to the key.

That way the server wont be able to see the key in the first place and the HSM would be acting as a black box.